# conditional/contingent model field choices

Tags: django, django-models

if I have a model that has two model choice fields, is there a way to make the choice set of the second field dependent on what is chosen in the first. Example, if given the following code, the User chooses APPLE for the "company" field — can the code be configured such that the User is presented ONLY the APPLE DIV_CHOICES for his "division" field choices?

```
CMP_CHOICES ('Apple', 'Apple Computers'),
            ('MS', 'Microsoft Inc.'),

APPLE DIV_CHOICES ( 'Desktop', 'Desktop'),
          ( 'iOS', 'iOS'),
          ( 'AS', 'AppStore'),

MS DIV_CHOICES ( 'Windows', 'Windows'),
           ( 'Longhorn', 'Longhorn'),
           ( 'Mobile', 'Mobile'),

class Contact(models.Model)
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=64, …)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=64, …)
company = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=CMP_CHOICES)
division = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=DIV_CHOICES)
....
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Choices must be all choices that are ever possible. However, you may use JavaScript on your form to limit the choices based on the first selection, but not on the model itself.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to accept one answer or another when both say essentially the same thing. Thank you both.

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of ways to go about this which will depend on whether you are using the django admin or your own custom code but out of the box it won't work - everything in the form is selectable by default.

You will end  up do this at the form level and template level, not in the model. You could create a [django form wizard](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/) to show the form in multiple stages. Alternatively you could use javascript to only show the APPLE/MS field after the CMP field has been selected. You could get fancier and do some ajax to dynamically load the APPLE/MS field after the CMP has been selected and validated.