# django chained modelchoicefields dynamic queryset

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have a form with two modelchoice fields to filter a line chart
The first modelchoicefield is filled with a list of providers

The second modelchoicefield must load a list of products of the selected provider
models:

```
class Proveedor(models.Model):
      id_proveedor = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
      nombre = models.CharField(max_length=150,blank=False,null=False)
      codigo_asignado =  models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=False,null=False)
      id_servicio = models.ForeignKey(Servicio,db_column='id_servicio',verbose_name='Servicio')
      class Meta:
            verbose_name_plural = "Proveedor"

      def __unicode__(self):
          return self.nombre

class Product(models.Model):
      id_lista = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
      fecha = models.CharField(max_length=12)
      id_prov = models.ForeignKey(Proveedor,db_column='id_proveedor', verbose_name='Proveedor')
      corto = models.CharField(max_length=15)
      conteo = models.IntegerField()
      dia = models.CharField(max_length=24)
      class Meta:
            managed=False
            db_table='pc_v_stat_corto'

  def __unicode__(self):
      return self.corto
```

Form:

```
class ChartCCForm(forms.Form):
      provider = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Proveedor.objects.all().order_by('nombre'),label='Proveedor')
      product = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=STAT_CORTO.objects.all(),to_field_name="corto",required=True)

      def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
          super(ChartCCForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
          self.helper = FormHelper()
```

my view

```
  def StatCortoView(request):
        formulario = ChartCCForm()
        prov = request.POST.get('id_proveedor')
        codigo = request.POST.get('codigo')
        mes = request.GET.get('mes')

        try:
            prov = prov
            codigo = codigo
            mes = mes
        except ValueError:
            prov = None
            codigo = None
            mes = None

        query = STAT_CORTO.objects.filter(id_prov=prov).filter(corto=codigo)
        ds = DataPool(
              series=
              [{'options': {
                  'source': query},
                  'terms': [
                     'dia',
                     'conteo']}
              ])
        cht = Chart(
            datasource = ds,
            series_options =
              [{'options':{
                  'type': 'line',
                  'stacking': False},
                'terms':{
                  'dia': [
                    'conteo']
                  }}],
            chart_options =
              {'title': {
                   'text': 'Codigos Cortos por Dia'},
               'xAxis': {
                    'title': {
                       'text': 'Fecha'}}})

        return render(request,'chartcc.html',
                                  {'grafico':cht,'form':formulario})
```

how can I update the product modelchoicefield based in the selected provider

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

What you are wanting isn't really possible using Django forms. The forms will only provide the choices it has when it is made, so you will have to product queryset all your possible products, and then filter them on the frontend using javascript.

See here: [conditional/contingent model field choices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7956480/conditional-contingent-model-field-choices)